# Parsing list of conda package specifications

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, conda

I want to parse a list of specifications (returned by `conda env export -n base --json --from-history --no-builds`) to obtain a list of packages and versions.

I have written the following code (without regex) that worked pretty well until `'conda-forge::blas[build=openblas]'` that is badly parsed into `'conda-forge::blas[build': {'openblas]'}` instead of `'conda-forge::blas[build=openblas]': set()`.

Here is a reproducible example with the result obtained and the expected result.

```py
dependencies = ['conda',
 'python=3.7',
 'xlrd',
 'numba=0.48',
 'conda-forge::blas[build=openblas]',
 'statsmodels=0.11']

packages_list = map(lambda x: x.split("=", 1), dependencies)
package_dict = {package[0]: set(package[1:]) for package in packages_list}

print(package_dict)

# {'conda': set(),
#  'python': {'3.7'},
#  'xlrd': set(),
#  'numba': {'0.48'},
#  'conda-forge::blas[build': {'openblas]'},
#  'statsmodels': {'0.11'}}

expected_result = {'conda': set(),
 'python': {'3.7'},
 'xlrd': set(),
 'numba': {'0.48'},
 'conda-forge::blas[build=openblas]': set(),
 'statsmodels': {'0.11'}}
```

Any help will be appreciated since I'm really bad at regex :-(.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had no answer I propose this solution that is not the more elegant, but it works.

```py
package_dict = dict()
for split in map(lambda x: x.split("=", 1), dependencies):
    # default values
    package = split[0]
    version = set()
    # cheking if it's a proper version by testing if the first char is a digit
    if len(split) > 1:
        if split[1][0].isdigit():
            # package + version
            version = set(split[1:])
        else:
            # The split was incorrect and the package shall not be splitted
            package = f"{split[0]}={split[1]}"
    package_dict[package] = version
```